# Rational Equations: What are Excluded Values?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

> I have an example rational equation in a textbook which I was able to solve:
>
> $$\dfrac{3}{x-6} = \dfrac{5}{x}$$

Least common denominator is : $x(x-6)$ so:

$$\frac{x(x-6)3}{x-6} = \dfrac{x(x-6)5}{x} = 3x = 5(x - 6)$$

$x = 15$

However, in my textbook, in addition I'm asked to provide "the excluded values". The provided solution says that the excluded values here are $6$ and $0$.

What does that mean and why are they $6$ and $0$?

Comment: By excluded values they mean the values for which the equation gets undefined. For eg, if denominator of RHS or LHS becomes 0, you can't define the equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may not divide with $0$ so $x-6\ne0$ and $x\ne 0$. And if you eventually get one of those as a solution you must refute it. Say you have $${x^2-1\over x-1}=2$$ after canceling we get $x+1=2$ so $x=1$. But this value is not OK since we would divide by $0$ at start.

Answer (score 1):

The excluded values of $x$ are those values, when substituted into any rational expression, that would make the denominator equal to $ 0 $. Any rational expression with the denominator being $ 0 $ is not defined.

In this case, the values of $x$ are $0$ and $6$ because 
$$\frac{3}{6-6} = \frac{3}{0} = undefined $$ and $$\frac{5}{0} = undefined $$